# Bootstrap 4 Grid - 3 Columns - 5.5 - 1 - 5.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Looks like half column sizing is doable in Boostrap 4.

I'm trying to do a basic responsive layout like the following. I realize they have to add to 12.

Column 1 (5.5) - Column 2 (1) - Column 3 (5.5)

This article seems to suggest it's possible? I want to ensure it keeps base gutters and spacing.

https://medium.com/wdstack/the-bootstrap-4-is-getting-odd-e9400b121719

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-55">
        Col 1 - 55%
    </div>
    <div class="col-05"> 
       Col 2 - 5%
    </div>
    <div class="col-55"> 
      Col 3 - 55%
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `auto-layout` columns combined with the grid columns as [explained in the article](https://medium.com/wdstack/the-bootstrap-4-is-getting-odd-e9400b121719)...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        5.5
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        5.5
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Io0HKVWjmD

Comment: Hmm that's not working as I'd expect. It's pushing the content in my 3rd column down to a second row.

Comment: It works in the codeply so you'll need to post your code